# Checkout/Rollback specific commit ID GIT (Possibly Duplicated)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio-2015, rollback

I have three commits, but i want to checkout the last commit and start working from there. But also keeping the other commits too i.e. when i commit again it will be a new commit and will not mess up my other commits :)

> Its also possibly a duplicated question, but since its a crucial
>   scenario I have  asked my own question.

If there is any GUI solution please prefer that solution because i am new at GIT :)

Best answer someone gave me is that : `git checkout -b old-state 0d1d7fc32` but i am not be able to do this :S

**Also if i revert two times to checkout the 3rd commit, it will delete the first two reverted commits?**

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which GUI tool you are using. I always use CLI. But the theory is the same.

1. create a new branch "branchA" that refers the newest commit 98ea8a1d
2. hard reset current branch "feature/RPG……" to commit f6f69dc1

So，the last two commits are protected by branchA. And current branch is rollbacked to f6f69dc1. And you can do things from f6f69dc1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to checkout the past commit to a branch using `git checkout <commit_hash> <new branch>`. Make your changes in `new branch` and then you can merge back.

But still it would have meant the same as doing the new changes directly on top of the three commits, so why do you want to do that ?

For your second question `git revert` will undo your commits but they will always be in your history so that you can use later